# How should I name classes? Is this name too long or unnecessarily long?

Tags: java, class, naming-conventions

I have the following top-level package: "com.gmail.email.aviersproject".
In this top-level package I have the class containing my main method and a package ".summonerdata".

My question is what I should name the class inside the "summonerdata" package.
The class will get summoner data by screen scraping a website.

Since the package that it's in is "summonerdata" is the classname "SummonerDataScreenScraper" unnecessarily long? Maybe just "ScreenScraper" or "Scraper" or "SdScraper" or "DataScraper"?

I've been told that it's important that the class names are discriptive while being as short as possible.

Comment: Keep them as fully descriptive as possible. Consider if you had to refactor package name. Also, this is off-topic.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: `SummonerDataScreenScraper` is fine, as a mix of abbreviated and written out names becomes messy. And the main IDEs have auto-completion like `SDSS`. Look for understandable nouns though: `Summon` maybe.

Comment: Java 1.6 had `InternalFrameInternalFrameTitlePaneInternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonWindowNotFocusedState` and in Java 1.7 it was shorted to `InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonWindowNotFocusedState` ;)

Answer (score 4):

There are many examples in the JDK itself. For example, `ConcurrentHashMap` is in the `java.util.concurrent` package, yet they felt that it was clearer to use concurrent in the name of the class too to differentiate it from other HashMaps.

I would use the long name, unless you only have one `Scraper` in your whole project, which happens to be a SummonerDataScreenScraper, but that becomes irrelevant because there is no alternative. In that case, a short name might be clear enough.